# using post throws IOExceptions on some phones

Tags: java-me, midp

i have created an application in J2ME that uses the following method to connect to a server. php is used on the Server side to process the requests. the application works fine on some phones like NOkia asha 303 but throws IOException on other phones what could be  the problem with this code. this method is called on a different thread. i also want to ask if you use post in j2me and set the

```
 httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

do you have to urlencode the data before sending or that is handled automatically by j2me

```
public String sendData(String serverUrl, String dataToSend) {

    String strResponse = "0"; //string to hold serverResponse
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
    HttpConnection httpConn = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    OutputStream outStream = null;
    try {
        //convert the dataToSend to bytes 
        String strData = dataToSend; //  get the data to Send and store it in a variable.
        byte[] dataToSendBytes = strData.getBytes();

        //open the Connection to the server.
        httpConn = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(serverUrl, Connector.READ_WRITE, true);

        if (httpConn != null) {
            httpConn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST); // method used to send the data.
            httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            httpConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.1");
            //httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US"); //language to use.
            //setRequestProperty("Connection", "close") ===> could generate or Solve IOExceptions on different mobile Phones.
            //httpConn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
            //setting the Content-length could have issues with some Servers===>
            //if the dataToSend is Empty String => contentLen = 0 , else get length of the dataBytes.
            String contentLen = ((dataToSend.length() > 0) ? Integer.toString(dataToSendBytes.length) : Integer.toString(0));
            //httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-length", contentLen); //not working on Emulator ....enable on shipping application.

            //open the output Stream to send data to the Server.
            outStream = httpConn.openOutputStream();

            // send the bytes of data to the Server.===> 
            //outStream.write(dataToSendBytes);

            //send the data bytes to the Server.
            int byteLen = dataToSendBytes.length; //length of byteToSend.
            for (int k = 0; k < byteLen; k++) {
                //send all the databytes to the Server.
                outStream.write(dataToSendBytes[k]);
            }

            //close the outputStream ===immediately after sending the data bytes to the Server===>eliminates the IOExceptions.
            closeOutStream(outStream);

            //get response code on Sending Data===> getting response code automatically flushes the output data.
            ntworkResponseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();

            if (ntworkResponseCode == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                //connection to the Server was okay.

                if (httpConn != null) {
                    //read the Response From the Server-----------
                    inputStream = httpConn.openInputStream(); // open the inputStream.

                    //get server Response Content length.
                    int contLen = (int) httpConn.getLength();
                    byte[] serverResponseBytes; //byte array to store the serverResponse.
                    if (contLen != -1) {
                        //store the serverResponse to a byte array.===> using a byte buffer could be faster.
                        serverResponseBytes = new byte[contLen];
                        inputStream.read(serverResponseBytes);

                        //convert the bytes to String and store them to the StringBuffer.
                        sb.append(new String(serverResponseBytes));

                    } else {
                        //serverResponse Length not available===> read character by character could be slower.
                        int read;
                        while ((read = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
                            sb.append((char) read);
                        }

                    }

                    //store the server response in a String.
                    strResponse = sb.toString();

                }
            } else {
                //connection problem occured.
                //throw new IOException("Http Response Code [" + ntworkResponseCode + "]");
            }

        }// the httpConnection Not null.--end.

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException arge) {
        strResponse = CONNECTION_EXCEPTION;
    } catch (ConnectionNotFoundException cone) {
        //a string to show we got an exception
        strResponse = CONNECTION_EXCEPTION;
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        //a string to show we got an exception
        strResponse = CONNECTION_EXCEPTION;
    } catch (SecurityException se) {
        //user cancelled the Connection Request.
        strResponse = CONNECTION_EXCEPTION;
    } finally {
        //close all the connection streams 
        try {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                //close the inputStream
                inputStream.close();
                inputStream = null;
            }

            if (outStream != null) {
                //close the outStream.
                outStream.close();
                outStream = null;
            }

            if (httpConn != null) {
                //close  the connection object.
                httpConn.close();
                httpConn = null;
            }

        } catch (IOException ie) {
              //show exception occured.
        }

    }
    //return server Response to the Client.
    return strResponse;
}
```

Comment: Did you track which line is throwing the IOException?

Comment: @Telmo Pimentel Mota i didnt track the line that threw the exception, my problem was that in some phones it was working okay without any exceptions but on other phones exceptions were thrown. i suspect the one of the setRequestProperty() methods. does it mean that sending by post is not standardized on j2me platform.

Comment: If it were standardized you would not be getting the error. :) Knowing the line that throws an exception is the first step to investigate the  issue.